# Google Sign-In breaks the display on mobile

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, google-signin

I'm trying to implement a Google Sign-in button with AngularJS, and while it works properly on desktop browser, on mobile (or even in "Device Mode") in Chrome's developers tools, it "breaks the display".

I noticed that the problem is with the fact that google's code pushes an iframe with "**left: -9999px;**", making the page scroll too far to the right.

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -9999px;" id="ssIFrame_google" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe#origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&amp;rpcToken=463269927.04673344&amp;clearCache=1"></iframe>
```

I added the following just for debugging purposes, and it resolved the problem, but I doubt this should be the solution.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0].style.left=0;
}, 2000);
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a style into your css that has

```
iframe { left: 0 !important }
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris, it worked like a charm. I am curious, though, if this is a common issue and how do people usually handle it, since I'd like to avoid "workarounds" that may stop working with future releases of angular/google.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way Google forces people to use iframes, there's really nothing you can do except a workaround.  The problem with iframes is you have almost no control over them; however, due to CORS, you can't just load the data into a div, which would be highly optimal.  Also, if you could mark my answer as the answer for your question, that would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Late addition: what I ended up doing was iframe { left: 0 !important ;visibility: hidden !important ;} because the iframe still appeared on the screen as a tiny, yet annoying, box.